# Cannot access shared folder on windows server from windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing, windows-server

I just share a folder on a server (windows server enterprise) but when I try to access from a pc (windows 7) appears a message saying "Windows cannot get access to \MyServer\Users\MyUser\MySharedFolder."
It says that maybe the path doesn't exists (which is false 'cause I checked it) or there might be a network problem.

On the server the "File Sharing" option is activated. Any idea why my pc isn't finding my server?

Cheers

Comment: This is not a programming question, and therefore is off-topic here. I've voted to migrate it to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com), where it's more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check Windows firewall settings? It may block your "Windows File And Printer Sharing" services and ports.

And also keep in mind if you share a folder on server with this path:

`C:\Users\MyUser\MySharedFolder` and server name is for example `MySever`, your path to shared folder on clients will be like this: `\\MyServer\MySharedFolder`.